# Connecting Terminal Blocks to Second PCB Board

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, header, screw-terminal

I have a daughterboard with 3.5mm screw terminal blocks (such as Digikey part # 277-5749-ND) 
that has to be connected to the mainboard, with the daughterboard either parallel or perpendicular to the mainboard.

However I do not find any 3.5mm male pin headers (http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en/connectors-interconnects/rectangular-board-to-board-connectors-headers-male-pins/1442672) to mount on the mainboard, so that the pin headers can be screwed into the daughterboard's screw terminal blocks. The closest is a 3.60mm pin header.

What is the recommended way of connecting them together? Using multiple single pin headers on the mainboard spaced 3.5mm apart?

[image]

Comment: Those are meant for wires, not board interconnect.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I was thinking about desoldering the terminal blocks and use male headers to join both boards together, but the spacing will still be 3.5mm

Comment: Did you try search `PHOENIX CONTACT - PST 1.0/5-3.5 - HEADER, PIN, VERTICAL, 3.5MM` -- multiple distributors. Vertical header strip.

Answer (score 1):

For a one off connection of two already designed boards, take standard cables with 0.1" headers (male or female as needed in your main board), and strip one end/cut in half. Either screw that into the terminal blocks, or solder it into the holes left from desoldering the blocks.

[image]

Or you could make some adaptor boards, that have standard 0.1" or 0.05" on one side, and use individual leads spaced 3.5mm on the other. A bit tedious to solder, but a cheap pcb and some breakaway male headers will only cost a few bucks.

[image]